# static variable doesn't increment in this code using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, output, increment

Why the value of static variable `a` is not incrementing even after return statement?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int p(int x);
int main()
{   
  int r=p(4);
  printf("%d",r);
  return 0;
}

int p(int x)
{
  static a=1;
  printf(" x = %d,a= %d\n",x,a);

  if(x<=1)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    printf(" x = %d,a= %d\n",x,a);    
    return p(x-1)+x+a++;
    printf(" x = %d,a= %d\n",x,a);    
  }
}
```

Here, when I print static variable `a` then all time its value is 1. But according to the theory I read, it should be incremented after each recursive call.

Comment: what is static a ? i think it would be static int a ..

Comment: The default data type of `static` variables is `int`.

Comment: Note: The `printf(" x = %d,a= %d\n", x, a);` after `return p(x-1)+x+a++;` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation of expression `p(x-1) + x + a++` is unspecified. We know that all three operands are evaluated *before* the sum is evaluated, but we do not know in what order they are evaluated (it is up to the compiler). In your case, the compiler first evaluates `p(x-1)`, so the value of `a` in the recursive function calls is always 1 and changes only after your program returns from all recursive calls.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137845/discussion-on-answer-by-dyz-static-variable-doesnt-increment-in-this-code-using).

Answer (score 1):

The incrementing function returns before post-increment of variable `a`. Logically, the second `printf` statement should not print.

Comment: NMDV, but I suppose it was DV'd for not being clear that the `printf()` preceding the `return` would not be expected ever to print the updated value of `a` anyway.  (As in, the downvoter probably did not recognize that this actually answers the question.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger This answer is not correct. The function call and the evaluation of a++, and indeterminately sequenced. The order is unspecified and behavior defined. See a very similar example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775973/is-this-undefined-behaviour-in-c-if-not-predict-the-output-logically/41777679#41777679 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532404/is-calling-a-function-with-local-side-effects-twice-in-the-same-expression-undef/40532729#40532729

Comment: @2501, *this* answer has nothing to do with the sequencing of a++ relative to the function call.  It points out that the `printf()` that is actually executed occurs before either one, in every recursive call, so only in the sense that the program's overall behavior is undefined could it ever see a value for `a` different from 1.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that code after a `return` is never executed. So this code block:

```
printf(" x = %d,a= %d\n",x,a);    
return p(x-1)+x+a++;
printf(" x = %d,a= %d\n",x,a);  <--- will never be executed!!
```

is really the same as

```
printf(" x = %d,a= %d\n",x,a);    
return p(x-1)+x+a++;
```

When you find the behavior of a piece of code strange/difficult to understand, it is often a good idea to rewrite complex expressions into a number of simple expressions.

This statement:

```
return p(x-1)+x+a++;
```

can be rewritten as:

```
int sum = 0;
sum = sum + p(x-1);  // Here you call the function again
sum = sum + x;
sum = sum + a;
a = a + 1;           // Here you increment a
return sum;
```

When you look at the rewritten code, it becomes clear that the recursive call of `p` happens **before** the increment of `a`. Consequently all prints of `a` is before the increment and will therefore print `1`.